# Pandas Groupby excluding missing column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 129971 rows.  I want to groupy 'country', then use groupby\transform
to fill missing values in the 'price' column with the mean from each group.

However, my 'country' column has 63 rows with NaN.

When I run this:

```
df['price'] = df.groupby("country")['price'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
print(df.isnull().sum())
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 129908 elements, new values have 129971 elements
```

I believe that is because of the 63 missing values in 'country'.  I can fix it easily enough by just
dropping the rows where country is NaN.

However, I found groupby.filter and was wondering if I could use it.

I have tried this:

```
df['price'] = df.groupby("country").filter(lambda x: x['country'].notnull())['price'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
print(df.isnull().sum())
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool
```

What I want is to grouppy 'country' where 'country' is not null so I can apply my transform
to fill missing 'price' values with the mean per group without dropping those 63 rows.

Comment: I just tried this:```df['price'] = df.groupby("country").filter(lambda x: df[df['country'].notnull()])['price'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
print(df.isnull().sum())```  but I now get this error: ```TypeError: filter function returned a DataFrame, but expected a scalar bool```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `assign` to temporarily assign a value for NaN country, then do `groupby` with `transform`:  Try this:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].fillna(df.assign(country=df['country'].fillna('-'))
                                   .groupby('country')['price'].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: ```@Scott Boston```, Much obliged.  ```print(df.isnull().sum())``` shows the correct country count of 63 and the missing price fields are populated.